# Is very short current spike harmful for a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

I am designing a buck converter and I have these current spikes:

[image]

They last about 25 us. The [MOSFET's](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfpg50.pdf) maximum current is 6.1 A. Would this fry the transistor?

Comment: What are we looking at? Where and how is it measured? Can you add a schematic, details on Vin/Vout, switching frequency, inductor specs, link to MOSFET and other datasheet etc?  If the waveform is the FET drain current then we need the FET datsheet to even start to answer the question.

Comment: *Maximum mosfet's current is 6,1A* Not really, read carefully, that 6.1 A is the maximum **continuous** current. For pulsed currents, the limits are different. See figure 11 in the datasheet. It also depends **how often** such a pulse occurs.

Comment: Datasheet allows higher peak current than 6.1A if there's not too much Vds at the same time and the pulse is repeated sparsely enough. and the devise is cooled well enough. We know nothing about these things. Nuch lower current would blow your mosfet if there's simultaneously so high Vds that the device operates well beyond the safe operating area.

Comment: _"I have these enter image description here current spikes."_ - that's not a spike, it's a ramp. How often does it repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified Answer:

Let me explain what I think : No It wont damage it.

What damages an electronic component?   **Current ?** **Voltage** ?** Is it always **Power** ? *No.*

***It is heat which damages an component***

And Heat(The energy dissipated) is nothing but Power times the Time it has been exposed to that power.

If you put an 0.25 watt rated 1 ohm resistor to say 10 V momentarily, it should be fried up as it would have 10A passing through it and would consume 100W !! of Power, but you can try it, It wont be fried, because the time it has been exposed to that power is short enough, say for 0.25s it would have 25J dissipated and will not damage the resistor.

Now but you may ask , the resistor doesnt have a current rating unlike your mosfet, indeed it has, just not explicit, it can easily be calculated to be 500mA (0.25=I^2 * 1 => I= 0.5A), so here power rating gives info about its rated current (this is somewhat how fuses work too, just that there current rating is given explicitly).

Similarly the current rating in your mosfet is also an power rating just given in terms of current, so its a type of rated power and momentarily breaking it wont be bad (but only momentarily).

If a 0.25 watt resistor can tolerate 100W for 0.25s , your MOSFET most likely can easily tolerate 6A across it for some micro seconds, but just make sure it doesn't do other problems, like say that current triggers another transistor or relay to turn on and do something undesirable, other than that, It most likely be fine.

Still if you are making some industrial grade thing, and feel you need more in depth suggestion , Please consider the above answers as they are in quite a depth.

If someone disagrees with me, please let me know in the comment, I will try to correct it.

**--- ****Update** : Thanks to [JonRB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572234/is-very-short-current-spike-harmful-for-a-mosfet/603205?noredirect=1#comment1585432_603205) for this suggestion-----**

Even a momentary High voltage might have some effects on some specific components , but it depends on how high the voltage is and normally these happen for "arcing" level voltages, for example:

In a Relay, if very high voltage is applied, it might internally weld its contacts and might make it shorted even when the high voltage goes away (it is sometimes helpful to strike the relay in these cases) ,

Similarly there are some insulators(dielectric) and some gel-junctions in mosfets, and this high voltage might damage the dielectric or the gel which is permanent damage (there are cracks on the edge of the die) , however it is quite rare for regular applications and is likely not your case, but still wanted to provide an accurate info

---

Comment: While I agree THERMAL is the major problem, VOLTAGE is a "do not pass go" Now an overvoltage does result in an avalanche that results in an overcurrent and an overtemp of the die, that doesn't always happen. An over-voltage can DESTROY a tile without any current flowing and the tell-tail sign is cracking around the edge - its rare to see as overvoltage -> avalanche is the usual route

Comment: @JonRB Could you please elaborate more on " An over-voltage can DESTROY a tile without any current flowing and the tell-tail sign is cracking around the edge" I didn't get it.

Comment: https://www.dynexsemi.com/Portals/0/assets/downloads/DNX_AN5945.pdf Fig5

Comment: @JonRB oo It is similar to like a high voltage pulse in relay which might internally weld its contact ? Isnt it, it is quite rare indeed but "treeing" is similar breakdown of dielectric due to high voltage . I get it.

Comment: yup, it also causes cracks on the edge of the die. it almost always is followed by a high current failure (and thus a crater and extensive damage) but every now and again you do catch it. If I was permitted I would share a picture, in 25+ years working in power electronics I have only ever been able to 100% prove over-voltage and it was due to the cracking, all other times "overvoltage leading to overcurrent is a possibility" when doing RRCA

Comment: @JonRB You are absolutely Correct, I edited the answer. Let me know if you agree with the edit, or I need to make some changes

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be well under the SOA curve for A-sec duration but the thermal response must be conducted very well with an average of 2/3 peak triangle of 7.5A , Pd~ 5A^2 x 2 ohms = 50 W if this is repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

> Is very short current spike harmful for a MOSFET?

That depends on which MOSFET you are using, how much current there is, and for how long, and what the MOSFET drain-source voltage is during the pulse.

The table on page 1 of your MOSFET datasheet says that it can take 6.1A of continuous current.  But that rating only applies to a DC current.

For current pulses you need to look at either the SOA curve in Figure 8, or the transient thermal response curve in figure 11.  Most MOSFETs will allows pulses of current much higher than the DC rating without harm.

**SOA:**
First let's look at the SOA graph (Figure 8).  Each curve represents the amount of energy that the MOSFET can handle on a certain time scale.  Note that the ammount of energy on each curve is typically constant.  Also note that the amount of energy decreases for shorter time scales.  For example...

- The 10ms curve shows 5A * 100V * 10ms = 5J.  It also shows 0.5A * 1000V * 10ms = 5J.
- The 1ms curve shows 7A * 200V * 1ms = 1.4J.  It also shows 3A * 500V * 1ms = 1.5J.
- The 100us curve shows 10A * 500V * 100us = 0.5J.  It also shows 6A * 800V * 100us = 0.48J.

Your LT-SPICE graph shows a current ramping from about 0A to 8A over 25us.  What it doesn't show is the voltage, so we can't calculate the energy dissipated by the pulse.  Without that energy number we can't determine if we are within the SOA curve limits.  To find the energy in LT-SPICE you can shift click on the part to get a graph of the part wattage vs time.  Next hold the CTRL key and click on the wattage trace and you will get a window that shows (among other things) the energy in the region of the trace currently on display.

If the energy shown is within the limits on the SOA curve, then the part should be OK.  The allowed energy over a 10 us interval is 160mJ.  The allowed energy over a 100s interval is 480mJ.  The allowed energy for 25us is going to be somewhere between 160mJ and 480mJ.  You can either try an estimate what that is, or just be conservative and use the curve for the shorter time scale (10us).